# Software Center not opening in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, software-center

I recently switched to Ubuntu GNOME. At first, software didn't work, so I tried these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It worked, but after some time it broke again, so I tried:

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Now it's broken again and Software Center is not even opening.
I tried all of these commands again as well as completely removing and reinstalling the software center, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug with the new Software Center that was added, starting with 16.04.

First ensure that it's not running in the background with:

```
$ killall gnome-software
```

Then remove the flawed configuration with:

```
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```